# AngularJS - Basic ng-repeat with ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I have a simple ng-repeat, that displays a list of statuses. I wanted to extend this ng-repeat to ng-switch to display a value depending on the status.

Current ng-repeat:

```
<td ng-repeat="myStatus in history.Status.slice(0, 12)">
    {{ myStatus }}
</td>
```

With ng-switch:

```
<td ng-repeat="myStatus in history.Status.slice(0, 12)" ng-switch="myStatus">
    <span ng-switch-when="1">test1</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2">test2</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="3">test3</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="4">test4</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="5">test5</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="6">test6</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="7">test7</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
</td>
```

However, witht eh above ng-switch, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works at my end, here is the **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XI8mCU5SMotcJWaOD3oe?p=preview)**

However as a suggestion i would prefer to use a function expression instead of ng-switch.

```
<td ng-repeat="myStatus in history.Status.slice(0, 12)">
    <span>{{getStatus(myStatus)}}</span>
</td>
```

`getStatus` is a function which would return the required information.

Comment: i think the issue is with my data layout in JSON.. Status: ["0", "1", "5", "0", "1", "1", "0","0","2","1","3","2","4"]

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
<td ng-repeat="myStatus in history.Status.slice(0, 12)" >
  <span ng-switch="myStatus">
    <span ng-switch-when="1">test1</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2">test2</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="3">test3</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="4">test4</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="5">test5</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="6">test6</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="7">test7</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>Error</span>
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: @HarutyunAbgaryyan - i think the issue is with my data layout in JSON.. Status: ["0", "1", "5", "0", "1", "1", "0","0","2","1","3","2","4"] ..... Can an array by sliced liek this?